# Pattern in regexp

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a pattern like:

```
string [number|number]
```

I want validate with RegExp in Java.

Case valid: `"blablabla blabla blabla [12|1234]"`

Any other would be invalid.

I don't realise how to do it.

Comment: Which programming language ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that: Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+\[\d+\|\d+\]$
```

Comment: I think he needs spaces and \w only handles alphanumeric and underscores